# why can't I see the original question link in this duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

visit: [Type checking of arguments Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734368/type-checking-of-arguments-python)

[image]

it's marked as duplicate, but duplicate of what? the upper duplicate banner is missing. Migration issue? Old question?

EDIT: in the meanwhile, Josh reinstated the original info, then I could hammer reopen then close, fixing the banner for good (okay, now I cannot reopen to answer...)

Comment: probably because it's old

Comment: At that point, the site just edited something into the post which could be removed/edited by users - it wasn't a separate banner...

Comment: @JonClements The post even pre-dates *that*.  The question was from back in the time where users were manually editing the link into the top of the question (which was done often enough that SE emulated the practice and automatically injected the link into the body of the question, which was later changed to being a proper banner that wasn't a part of the question itself).  You can see as much from the revision history.

Comment: sorry for posting a duplicate. I searched meta using google but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: @Servy strangely glad I missed that party by 3 years :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The banner being a separate element at the top was site functionality added sometime after this question was closed.

Prior to that time, a pseudo-banner would be added as text to the question body (sometimes [manually by users](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/734368/3), if you go back far enough). In this case, [it was removed sometime last year](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/734368/5). I assume the editor thought that the new automatic banner would be added.

I've rolled back the edit to restore the pseudo-banner. The better solution would be for a gold badger to re-open and re-close the question. Although this would change the timestamp, it would fix the banner.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. For the record, I reopened, then closed the question with the proper duplicate banner.

Comment: Oh, great, I was just editing to suggest that, thanks.

Comment: it's the first time I'm using dupehammer like this ! i'll accept the answer as soon as I can so you can enjoy 0 extra meta-rep.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre congrats or something!? :p

Comment: @JonClements yeah, I think we can say that :) using dupehammer to fix the old questions :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's okay now and then, but it's usually quite pointless to reopen to close again... definitely not worth the effort of doing so if you didn't happen to have a hammer there.

Comment: @JonClements of course, no need to bother 5 people to reopen and 5 to close otherwise... changing the duplicate target is now easy with "edit" button ... well, when it shows :)

Comment: @Jean I tried that before - tried adding a new dupe, removed the original dupe, saved it, added back the original, removed the other one and saved it... saved the dupe links backend wise, but didn't cause the system to introduce the banner.

Comment: I mean: in new questions. on old questions it looks like you have to reopen/close. But mods don't have open/close limits so not a problem for you.