# Is this supposed to say that there is no answers?

Tags: support

Close reason of [HTML entity for check mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183982/html-entity-for-check-mark)

> This question already has answers here:
>
> Closed 9 years ago.

Is this supposed to say that there is no answers? or usual *Halloween spooking*?

*Cody gray reopened the post, then closed it, then edited/removed something, and then re-closed it as "Original close reason(s) were not resolved"? I mean he could have edited the post without reopening and re-closing?*

Comment: The banner is the section containing "This question already has answers here:". Generally you would have a link to the duplicate question or target there. _In this case_ that link is edited into the question body. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13183982/timeline . This was closed  _before_ duplicate links were added in the sentence itself

Comment: Isnt that what you are asking?

Comment: @SurajRao I think this is a bug - I mean Cody gray said that it was a duplicate of X when in the act "close", let's forget his edits on the question body, now?

Comment: No Its not a bug. The moderator reopened and then closed it again as a duplicate of the same question so that the link is now shown in the banner

Comment: @SurajRao Now I saw it, so the time of I asked this and he corrected this was all coincidence... Can you make an answer for this...?

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361445/why-cant-i-see-the-original-question-link-in-this-duplicate

Comment: @SurajRao thanks for our help: the duplicate of my question has an excellent answer, read it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391506/17040857